# Downgrading httpd on centos4 with yum

Tags: centos, httpd, yum

A server currently has httpd-2.0.63-2.el4s1.centos.2 installed (from the centosplus repo) but that version is missing some security updates. Where as httpd-2.0.52-49.ent.centos4 is a lower version, but it does have recent security updates. So I need to downgrade.

It looks like the only way would be to remove it and then install 2.0.52. Would this mess up any configurations? Should I backup all the conf files first?

Comment: You should always back up your configuration files, even if you're sure they won't be replaced. :)

Comment: Ya, after I asked the question, I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to `yum erase httpd` (and this did NOT remove any configuration files.) It did however, uninstall some PHP packages. So, I just had to watch which ones and then reinstall them.

Comment: Only use answers to answer your own question, not to post comments. If you want to add to your original question, then edit the question and append your updates.

Comment: @Echo Why don't you clean this up a little and mark it as your answer?  (Since this was your solution.)

Comment: @AaronCopley I was going to, but totally forgot about it. Also, the down-voting made me think it wouldn't be helpful to others. Thanks for the clean up.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed and upgraded httpd through yum, then you can do `yum downgrade httpd` to go down to the previous version.

Usually package upgrades don't touch configuration files, but just in case, I would run this first:

`cd /etc/httpd; tar cvfz /var/tmp/httpd_backup.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz *`

This will create a dated backup in /var/tmp.

If you want to prevent future updates, consider using the yum plugin `yum-versionlock` as well.

Comment: `Downgrade` will in fact take you to the previous version, but in this case it's a different package from a different repository entirely and won't work as described.